# How to install libesedb? Build error

Tags: linux, compiling

I'm trying to build the libesedb package so I can read edb files.

I went to: http://code.google.com/p/libesedb/wiki/Building and found the following:

```
tar xfv libesedb-alpha-<version>.tar.gz
cd libesedb-<version>
./configure
make
```

So I extracted the files into the folder `libesedb-20120102`

I then cd to the folder and used `./configure` - it returned the following:

```
si@siMint ~/Desktop/libesedb-20120102 $ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/si/Desktop/libesedb-20120102':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I ran `make` anyway, and got this:

```
si@siMint ~/Desktop/libesedb-20120102 $ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

I'm using Linux Mint (16, Cinnamon).

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `./configure` script returns an error regarding your c-compiler. There are some compiler tests that are not working with your gcc.

I tried the same on my machine (debian 6) with gcc version 4.4.5 and the `./configure` script succeeded without an error.

So check your gcc version with

```
gcc --version
```

and install another version if necessary. In the official repositories are always different versions of gcc see with:

```
apt-cache search gcc | grep ^gcc
```

I recommend the version 4.4, because it worked for me, so after installing it change the link of `gcc`, see:

```
ls -la /usr/bin/gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Dec 29 18:19 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.4
```

and check again with `gcc --version`.

`./configure` or make errors are often depending on a wrong gcc version.

Comment: I tried the permission command and got the following:

si@siMint ~ $ lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Dec 29 18:19 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.4

lrwxrwxrwx: command not found

Comment: That's not a command that's the output of the command `ls -la /usr/bin/gcc` and it says that the link `gcc` points to `gcc-4.4`.